# Links to good answers which are subsequently deleted

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions

In an answer of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49600743) I referenced [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37782238) from 2 years earlier. This second answer was later deleted along with the entire question. For those who can't view that deleted Q&A, the question was voted +8/-0 and the answer +13/-0 at the time of deletion, so it was certainly well received.

Now, I can understand why the second question was closed as a duplicate of other ones. What I don't understand / appreciate is the following:

1. **Why was it deleted?** Sounds like a good signpost at a minimum. The answer appears to be appreciated. 2 years later it managed to somehow attract 4 delete votes.
2. **What can we do to find / update bad links?** I just happened to be reviewing an answer of mine. Is there a way to systematically check for links which point to deleted questions / answers?

Any advice / pointers are appreciated.

---

**Update:** As noted in comments, the second Q&A has now been undeleted. I believe, however, my 2 questions are still relevant, i.e. How did that question get into a delete queue? Is there a way to find such "broken" links?

Comment: The why is clear. The voters saw that all the important information was already on the targets duplicates, and the question itself isn't much different from the targets duplicates.

Comment: @Braiam, So *what's the process?* For example, I don't see a "Delete" link on all duplicate questions. Does it feed a queue (if so, what criteria?), or is there a magic "Delete" vote link I don't have access to.

Comment: [Only those that are 48 hours old or have score less than -2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), I believe. I presume you already read that help page.

Comment: I recommend you not to go hunting deleted post. Strive to make sure they aren't qualified for deletion in the first place.

Comment: @Braiam, Doesn't work, I typically link to *good answers*, irrespective of whether target is a duplicate, purposefully so. Besides, doesn't really solve the general problem.

Comment: That's a weird response from a quality oriented individual. If you link to good answers you should also make sure that the question it is posted to is *good*. An stellar answer that nobody can find isn't so stellar.

Comment: @jpp For (1), it's entirely possible for 4 high-rep users to come across the question, think that it's not very useful and click the (delete) button.

Comment: For (2), I guess some SEDE is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What can we do to find / update bad links? I just happened to be reviewing an answer of mine. Is there a way to systematically check for links which point to deleted questions / answers?

For now, SEDE can help with that:

- [Questions answered by a specific user that link to deleted questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/888697)
   (for maintaining your answers)
- [Questions that link to a (possibly deleted) question](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/888529)
- [Most linked to deleted questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/888708)

Comment: I recommend against undeleting the questions themselves.

Comment: @Braiam, Based on what exactly? My view is broken links *should* be carefully assessed, and the *community* via votes should decide whether a Q&A should exist or not. Usually there's some to-and-fro with a delete / undelete cycle or two, but most cases there's an equilibrium which decides the end-point.

Comment: @jpp well, you are now saying that the voters didn't take into account the effects of their actions. Other than the broken link, haven't you found an alternative non-deleted resource?

Comment: @Braiam, Please don't put words in my mouth. I asked a question and gave my opinion. There is no need to extrapolate / construe your own negative interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

My second question has been nicely answered by @duplode. With regards to the first, the "Deleting questions" privilege comes with the following advice:

> **When should I delete questions?**
>
> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be
>   flagged and deleted.
>
> Before voting to delete, **please check whether there are any good
>   answers**; if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator
>   attention as a potential merge candidate. **We don't like to lose great
>   answers!**

Now I entirely appreciate this is subjective. Poor answers which happen to be old can accumulate unwarranted upvotes. However, [this +14/-0 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782066/list-vs-generator-comprehension-speed-with-join-function/37782238#37782238) doesn't fall into that category. It contains specific and useful information regarding `str.join`, namely a reference to the relevant C-level source code, not found in other answers.

Appropriately, the question has now been undeleted.